# Alternative to CurvyCorners

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, curvycorners

Is there an alternative script to CurvyCorners that does border-radii based on CSS? CurveryCorners has so many bugs and rarely works the way it's expected to, it's just not worth using anymore.

Thanks.

Comment: The prevailing opinion is that you just use CSS border-radius as "progressive enhancement". In browsers that don't support it, the squared corners are just a cosmetic difference (ie. not a big deal). I've used pure-CSS curved corners but they require at least 3 nested divs just for a cosmetic effect. Not worth it.

Comment: +1 to stuffing the losers without a CSS3 capable browser...:)

Comment: I mean that it should be javascript that reads from the CSS `border-radius` property. I'm personally under the same opinion, but my project manager would like to have rounded corners on our clients sites in older browsers.

Comment: @Rev - CSS3Pie solves the problem. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alternative is to use the CSS3 `border-radius` style.

This works out-of-the-box in all current browsers, except IE8 and earlier. For browsers other than IE, you shouldn't be running any kind of script at all for this, as it's a standard built-in feature in the browser.

For IE8 and earlier, there is a hack called [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com) which allows IE to also support the standard CSS3 `border-radius` style. This is Javascript based, but works with the standard CSS code, meaning you can use the same style for *all* browsers.

As an added bonus, CSS3Pie also implements CSS3 box shadows and gradients for IE as well. And it's under active development, and the author is great at helping people out on the forum if they're having problems with it.

Comment: Worked great for me where curvyCorners was having all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 0):

In the past i've used [Diller Design's](http://dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/) Roundies which has always worked pretty well for me.

It uses VML to create the rounded edges.

UNfortunatley i don't think the author is updating it any more.